# Summing edges properties for order by in select statement

Tags: sql, graph, properties, graph-theory, orientdb

I'm trying to do a select statement to order the result set by force of connections between them.

```
CREATE CLASS Entity EXTENDS V;
CREATE CLASS isConnectedTo EXTENDS E;

CREATE PROPERTY isConnectedTo.strength INTEGER;
```

**'isConnectedTo'** edges relate **Entities** to another **Entities**

The tricky part is I have double connections between the same entities as so:

```
CREATE VERTEX Entity SET name = "John";
CREATE VERTEX Entity SET name = "Mike";
CREATE VERTEX Entity SET name = "Susan";

CREATE EDGE isConnectedTo FROM (SELECT FROM Entity WHERE name = "Mike") TO (SELECT FROM Entity WHERE name = "John") SET strength = 3;
CREATE EDGE isConnectedTo FROM (SELECT FROM Entity WHERE name = "Mike") TO (SELECT FROM Entity WHERE name = "Susan") SET strength = 4;
CREATE EDGE isConnectedTo FROM (SELECT FROM Entity WHERE name = "John") TO (SELECT FROM Entity WHERE name = "Mike") SET strength = 2;
```

So **Mike** is connected to **John** which is connected to him too. Also **Mike** is connected to **Susan**.

In this case if I were to run my desired query on Mike it should return:

1. **John**
2. **Susan**

by this order because the sum of strength between Mike and John is **3 + 2 = 5** and between Mike and Susan is only **4**.

I've iterated through many possible queries to no avail but I can't seem to figure why this last one refuses to work.

```
LET $main = SELECT FROM Entity WHERE name = "John";
LET $vset = SELECT expand(in('isConnectedTo')) FROM $main;
SELECT @rid, eval('$ei.strength + $eo.strength') as total_strength FROM $vset
   LET $ei = (SELECT expand(inE('isConnectedTo')) FROM $current WHERE $main.@rid IN out),
   LET $eo = (SELECT expand(outE('isConnectedTo')) FROM $current WHERE $main.@rid IN in)
ORDER BY total_strength DESC;
```

Note: I already got the Entities' names indexed with a hash dictionary and the 'isConnectedTo' edges are indexed with unique links between Entities (hence they cannot be repeated in the same direction)

All the other trials I did or help from the other answers here result in query times of >= 2 mins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd like to propose a small change on your domain. Don't create 2 edges in case both people are connected, but use the same edge with 2 properties.

```
CREATE CLASS Entity EXTENDS V;
CREATE CLASS isConnectedTo EXTENDS E;
CREATE PROPERTY isConnectedTo.strengthOut INTEGER;
CREATE PROPERTY isConnectedTo.strengthIn INTEGER;

CREATE VERTEX Entity SET name = "John";
CREATE VERTEX Entity SET name = "Mike";
CREATE VERTEX Entity SET name = "Susan";

CREATE EDGE isConnectedTo FROM (SELECT FROM Entity WHERE name = "Mike") TO (SELECT FROM Entity WHERE name = "John") SET strengthOut = 3, strengthIn = 2;
CREATE EDGE isConnectedTo FROM (SELECT FROM Entity WHERE name = "Mike") TO (SELECT FROM Entity WHERE name = "Susan") SET strengthOut = 4;
```

In this was you have less edges and you can use this super fast query:

```
SELECT out.name as name1, in.name as name2, eval('strengthOut + strengthIn') as strength
FROM (
  SELECT expand( bothE('isConnectedTo') ) FROM Entity WHERE name = "Mike"
) ORDER BY strength
```

*NOTE: Remember to create an index on Entity.name to speedup the inner query.*

Comment: Thank you Lvca! Didn't think of this before! Going to try it as soon as I can! However I've got to change the script that populates the Entities and fetch them all over again. Going to try this with the set I specified below of ~38000 entities and then scale it to the millions if it works out well! ;)

Comment: This works GREAT! Finally! But it doesn't seem to work without **expand()** ing the edges... Do you know why, Lvca?

Comment: You're right, without expand the subquery just returns 1 document with a collection inside. I've changed my answer to include the expand().

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

```
select expand(rid) from (select @rid,sum($a[0].sum,$b[0].sum) as sum from Entity 
let $a= (select sum(strength) as sum from isConnectedTo where in.name="Mike" and out.name=$parent.current.name),
$b= (select sum(strength) as sum from isConnectedTo where out.name="Mike" and in.name=$parent.current.name)
where name<>"Mike" order by sum desc)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering! This one works!
However this is taking a LOT of time due to the fact that it is searching every entity and then excluding them based in where clauses. Maybe there's a way of starting from "Mike" and not having to traverse all entities?

Comment: Try this query : select expand(myRid) from (select myRid,sum(strength) from (select expand($c)
let $a=(select out.@rid as myRid,strength from (select expand(inE("isConnectedTo")) from Entity where name="Mike")),
 $b=(select in.@rid as myRid,strength from (select expand(outE("isConnectedTo")) from Entity where name="Mike")),
 $c=unionAll($a,$b)
) group by myRid order by sum desc)

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
select expand($a.rid) from (select from Entity where name="Mike")
let $a=(select @rid,sum(bothE().strength) as sum from Entity where both('isConnectedTo').name contains $parent.current.name group by name order by sum desc)
```

Comment: Thank you Michela! This is slightly faster.
However with a small set of ~38000 entities it still takes 122 seconds.
Note: I'm planning of having a set of Entities in the order of millions. ~1m-5m